# why is my textView not found in the android ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have written the following code:

```
TodosOverviewActivity extends ListActivity{

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);
            this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
            registerForContextMenu(getListView());
            fillData();
        }



    private void fillData() {

    fetchEvents();

     adapter2 = new MySimpleArrayAdapter
                (this, nameOfEvent, startDates, descriptions);
     setListAdapter(adapter2);
            }

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.todo_row_title);
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.todo_row_date);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.todo_row_image);

            titleTextView.setText(mTitles[position]);

    ..

    }
```

However it fails on nullpointer `titleTextView`. What am I missing?

Comment: post an XML of the `todo_list`

Comment: added. can you please advise? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this -  in `getView()`:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);
```

to:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, parent, false);
```

For your code sake I hope in `fillData()` the method `fetchEvents();` doesn't trigger networking on UI thread :)

Comment: I'll split to another thread. Btw, how can I know if querying the G-calendar app works offline with local app or requires network?

Comment: To add a bit of explanation: you're trying to find views that haven't been inflated. You've inflated todo_list.xml and you're using that to find a view with an id of "todo_row_image" which is not part of the view hierarchy for todo_list, so that call returns null, hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: @Elad I'm not sure off hand how to know that other than testing it. If it does require networking it will crash if you do it on the UI thread.

Comment: @ChristopherGillis: thanks for adding that ... I am sure the author introduced a typo and he wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list, null);
```

and don't forget to return `rowView` at the end of the function.